# How do I set the localization of my project so DateTime.Parse will use it?

Tags: c#, datetime, localization

Our software was deployed to a server that was set in the control panel to be within the US, with MM/dd/yyyy format. As a result, instances of `DateTime.TryParse()` in the code used the local format of the machine, not the format of our dev machines which are UK `dd/MM/yyyy`.

I can see that I can force it to use a specific localization, but what I'd like to do is pop something in the global file or web/app config to make it always use UK format, so that I don't have to specify it for every DateTime operation.

Any idea how I do this? Bonus if I can configure it in Visual Studio to force this into new projects so people don't forget.

Comment: Write a utility method of `TryParseUkDateTime`? That's the *simplest* approach... Beyond that, we're likely to need to know the type of application you're writing.

Comment: here's the spec https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It'll be applications across the board, mvc, windows forms, windows service, and WCF services. I was hoping for something I could pop into the global.asax or config

Comment: I would be much more confident in just being explicit every time - via common helper methods where appropriate - than using an app.config, myself. (I'd also try to minimize the number of date/string conversions you do - never use them for database storage, for example.)

Comment: Would you introduce that into your company's developer guidelines for code? Chapter 3, All developers will explicitly declare the localization when using `DateTime.Parse` to ensure expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such setting (for desktop applications). But you could put this into all entry points of your application(s):

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

However, that would make localization impossible. I would prefer explicitly specifying the culture in the parse methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Use this approach if you want to set the default culture and user interface culture for all the pages in a Web application.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="Fr-FR"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```